# Nodejs Stormpath authentication error

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

I'm following this tutorial to understand the basics of stormpath: https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app/

I've followed exact steps but after login I get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined    at
>   Application.authenticateApplicationAccount [as authenticateAccount]
>   (C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express-stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\lib\resource\Application.js:135:53)
>   at forms.loginForm.handle.success
>   (C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express-stormpath\lib\controllers.js:215:43)
>   at C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\lib\forms.js:94:63    at
>   C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\lib\forms.js:55:21    at done
>   (C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:132:19)
>   at
>   C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:16
>   at C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\lib\forms.js:52:25    at
>   C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\lib\fields.js:58:21    at
>   Object.async.eachSeries
>   (C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:142:20)
>   at Object.b.validate
>   (C:\work\nodejs\node_modules\forms\lib\fields.js:48:23)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Turns out I had access issues on my mac and some modules were not installed properly. This issue has been resolved. How do I close the thread?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Most quality questions include a small code sample that folks can use to spot bugs or reproduce your issue. I think that might be necessary in this case. Could you edit your question to include relevant parts of your code?

Based on the stack trace alone however I think the problem is that your Stormpath application has no login attempts: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-node/blob/7485fb9/lib/resource/Application.js#L136

Comment: This may be your issue here actually: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express/issues/71

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you show us how you're requiring the Stormpath library, setting up the api key variables, etc?